# How to store state and analog signal together in DB

Tags: time-series-database

I want to acquire data from 1 proximity and 3-axis accelerometers with 100-150 Hz sampling rate in 16 bit resolution. The proximity sensor is a reference for the rough reconstruction of the angular position of the spinning wheel. Data are time series and all channels must be recorded in a single time domain.

My question is, how can I store the trigger time of the proximity sensor along 3 acceleration data? In binary all zeros and 1 for the trigger time? What if trigger time and sampling time do not overlap? What are the practices for this type of task?

This is how I imagine it all:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| X | Y | Z | Trigger |         Timestamp         |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 2 | 4 | 4 |    0    | 2013-09-03 10:45:27.00001 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 3 | 3 | 3 |    0    | 2013-09-03 10:45:27.00002 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 4 | 2 | 3 |    1    | 2013-09-03 10:45:27.00003 |      // 6 o'clock position
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 3 | 1 | 4 |    0    | 2013-09-03 10:45:27.00004 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 2 | 1 | 5 |    0    | 2013-09-03 10:45:27.00005 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 3 | 1 | 4 |    0    | 2013-09-03 10:45:27.00006 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 2 | 1 | 5 |    0    | 2013-09-03 10:45:27.00007 |
...
```

[image]

Comment: Cool picture, but your question is unclear. Are you asking how to create a table with 5 columns, one of which is a timestamp? Are you asking if bit fields are supported by your DBMS? What _is_ your DBMS?

Comment: I am thinking of using InfluxDB. But still learning. 
I want to know, in which way trigger times of Hall-effect sensor can be stored in DB? Because it is not an analog data, which has different values. Signal has two states, most of the time it is false, but true when magnet on wheel passes by fixed Hall-effect sensor.
P.S. Maybe it is hard to understand, because the application is not related to DB.